# Read elimination and concurrency

Tags: c#

Given the following simple code:

```
class Program
{
    static bool finish = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(ThreadProc).Start();
        int x = 0;
        while (!finish)
        {
            x++;
        }
    }

    static void ThreadProc()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        finish = true;
    }
}
```

and running it in the Release mode with MSVS2015(.NET 4.6) we will get a never ending application. That happens because the JIT-compiler generates code which reads `finish` only once, hence ignoring any future updates.

The question is: why is the JIT-compiler allowed to do such an optimization? What part of the specification allows it?

Comment: I suppose, making `finish` `volatile` solves this issue, right?

Comment: @dymanoid, of course, but the question is different :)

Comment: The compiler is free to do any optimization as long as it doesn't alter the correctness of the program *when run on a single thread*. Even the stupidest compiler that does a straightforward compilation with no optimizations will still be tripped up by the hardware doing its own optimizations. If you're dealing with multi-threading, you have very few guarantees.

Comment: @Luaan, compiler plays by the rules, that's why I had the question. I didn't find the rule which allows such an optimization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is covered in section 10.5.3 - Volatile Fields in the [C# Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

*(I've emphasized the part which covers your observations below)*

> 10.5.3 Volatile Fields
>   When a field-declaration includes a volatile modifier, the fields introduced by that declaration are volatile fields.
>   **For non-volatile fields, optimization techniques that reorder instructions can lead to unexpected and unpredictable results in multithreaded programs that access fields without synchronization**, such as that provided by the lock-statement (§8.12). These optimizations can be performed by the compiler, by the runtime system, or by hardware. For volatile fields, such reordering optimizations are restricted:
>   * A read of a volatile field is called a volatile read. A volatile read has “acquire semantics”; that is, it is guaranteed to occur prior to any references to memory that occur after it in the instruction sequence.
>   * A write of a volatile field is called a volatile write. A volatile write has “release semantics”; that is, it is guaranteed to happen after any memory references prior to the write instruction in the instruction sequence.
>   These restrictions ensure that all threads will observe volatile writes performed by any other thread in the order in which they were performed. A conforming implementation is not required to provide a single total ordering of volatile writes as seen from all threads of execution.

Comment: heh, great statement. So I suppose it is a C# way to say that the behavior is undefined in such cases. Thank you!

Comment: Most likely it is implementation specific **exactly** what happens, meaning that if you run the exact same code in .NET core, or in Xamarin or in Mono or on Linux or in an IoT device, the code *may* behave differently. Although "unexpected and unpredictably" would cover it, it will probably not burn your house down :)

Comment: This is indeed the part of the specification that says "all bets are off". It's also woefully inadequate at explaining what might happen, so "covered" might be a little too strong a word. Section I.12.6 of ECMA-335 (which covers the runtime) has a little more to say on the topic. (Though not *much* more. And of course the C# standard has to make sense on its own.)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler thinks (makes the following promises) as follows:

> I will execute your code in the order that you've
>   asked me to, that is any instructions that run in your single-threaded
>   code will be performed in the order they were written and based on
>   this I will do any optimizations I please, that conform with
>   single-threaded sequentiality.

Well, the compiler sees the `finish` variable not marked as `volatile` and thus he considers that it will not be changed by other threads, so he optimizes that away into considering the condition as being always true. 
On Debug mode, it has a more lax thinking and does not perform this optimization away.

More on this [here](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/).

Comment: That's not what I asked for. I understand the behavior but didn't understand what part of the specification allows it.